# If running parallel FTP-Clients (consumers) on one directory, how can i be sure, that one file will not be snaped twice and be proceed twice?

Tags: java, docker, ftp, apache-camel, docker-swarm

I have a Java-Application with a Camel route with an FTP-Consumer and this application will be deployed als a Docker Service on a Docker Host. A Docker Service can be scaled, so that multiply FTP-Clients polling the same FTP directory.

> I want to be sure, that one file will not be snaped twice by 2
>   consumers. What can I do to achive this?

Comment: why not clone working folder for each docker instance?

Comment: I don't really understand your purpose, could you explain, what can I achive with the clones of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

From [Camel FTP component doc](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html),

> The FTP consumer (with the same endpoint) does not support concurrency
>   (the backing FTP client is not thread safe)

---

> I want to be sure, that one file will not be snapped twice by 2
>   consumers. What can I do to achieve this?

Recall the fact above, the simplest way to achieve this is to ensure only 1 active consumer (towards same endpoint) across all application.

This can be done by having a common config in a shared resources (e.g. DB) to control which application could activate the consumer (by [controlbus component](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html)).

Comment: "The FTP consumer (with the same endpoint) does not support concurrency (the backing FTP client is not thread safe)" - yes, I think they mean within one application. But there must be some way to handle this problem whithout a contolling the resources from outside...

Comment: @Oli Normal FTP consumer is performing Connect, Authentication, Scan, Pick File. If you want to achieve your goal by multiple active consumer, you need a  mechanism to let each application to know what file it should collect. A side note: you may have a look at [Idempotent Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) which is support by Camel FTP